# Yii2 bootstrap table on the PDF is half width when deployed on the server

Tags: php, twitter-bootstrap, yii2, mpdf, kartik-v

In my Yii2 application I use kartik mpdf to generate PDF from html.
I have a table on a PDF that is full width in my local machine (Windows) which is the expected behaviour. However, when I deploy it on the Ubuntu server, the table is half width.

I have cross checked the dependecy versions and both the enviornments have identicle dependencies as well.

I confirmed that the parent containers (div) of the table are behaving normally by placing texts within them. Its only the `<table>` element that gets dropped in size in the whole PDF when deployed.

```
<div class="row">
 <div class="col-lg-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-xs-12">
  <div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-bordered" >
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
  </div>
 </div>
</div>
```

This is my code for the table without the body.

Any idea whats happening behind and how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After many struggles, I found that MPDF shrinks the table to fit the tallest row into one page. If you have multiple rows (cells) merged vertically then you'll run into this.

> tables will resize so that the tallest row (cell) will fit on a page - this is the only one that cannot be overridden

[It is mentioned in the troubleshooting section of the documentation.](https://mpdf.github.io/troubleshooting/resizing.html)

Answer (score 1):

You can add additional CSS:

```
$pdf = new Pdf([
    ..........
    'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
    'cssInline' => '',
    .........
]);
```

With this css file my table are with 100% width. You can insert your own css file or add you css classes in cssInline

Comment: But this cssFile is applied by default don't? It's a good idea to use this one, instead of general bootstrap because of all the restrictions for CSS of the mpdf library.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling with the great [kartik/yii2-mpdf](https://github.com/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf) a couples of days ago and I learnt something. Just give to it the minimum CSS you need. For example, rules containing `!important` are totally ignored.

For this full width table, try adding `style="width: 100%;"` to the table tag.